# Java Double Stream sort in reverse order

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, double, reverse

I am learning about Java Streams and I have created some functions to test and I am struggling to find a way to sort in reverse order

Here is the code:

```
public class StreamCreator {

    public List<Fruit> getMixedFruitList() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Fruit(true),
                new Orange(),
                new BloodOrange(),
                new BloodOrange(),
                new BloodOrange(),
                new Orange(),
                new Fruit(),
                new Mango(),
                new Mango(),
                new Mango(),
                new BloodOrange()
        );
    }

    public Stream<Fruit> getFruitStream() {
        return getMixedFruitList().stream();
    }

    public Stream<Fruit> getParallelFruitStream() {
        return getMixedFruitList().parallelStream(); // Works
        //return getMixedFruitList().stream().parallel(); //Works
    }

    public Stream<String> getStringStream() {
        return Stream.of("A", "h", "c", "z", "Z", "b", "H", "M", "o", "9", "3", "8", "2", "1");
    }

    public IntStream getIntStreamByRange(int start, int end, boolean closed) {
        return (closed) ?
                IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end) :
                IntStream.range(start, end);
    }

    public LongStream getLongStreamByRange(long start, long end, boolean closed) {
        return (closed) ?
                LongStream.rangeClosed(start, end) :
                LongStream.range(start, end);
    }

    public DoubleStream getDoubleStream() {
        return DoubleStream.of(1.3, 98.7, 48.46, 68.47, 2.5, 6.7, 4.6, 9.2, 100.5, 4.6, 0.48, 3.0);
    }


}

public static void intermediateOperatorsEg2() {
        streamCreator
                .getDoubleStream()
                .sorted()
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(sorted -> System.out.print(sorted + ", "));

        streamCreator
                .getDoubleStream()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())

                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //filterExample();
        //intermediateOperatorsEg1();
        intermediateOperatorsEg2();
    }
```

When I do Comparator.reverseOrder() I get the following error:

```
'sorted()' in 'java.util.stream.DoubleStream' cannot be applied to '(java.util.Comparator<T>)'
```

Then if I try:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::valueOf))
```

It doesn't work,
If the stream is passing down each double value, what is the best way to reverse this ?

Comment: maybe you should call boxed() before you sort it then pass the Comparator.reverseOrder()?

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly, thanks, I would love to know why, some suggest this is an expensive operation? but great thanks

Comment: thats because the comparator takes a generic type T, meaning it cannot take a primitive. Thus, you need to use the wrapper class Double. Java has built in boxing/unboxing for some operations, but here you need to explicitly call boxed(). but imagine a large list of numbers and you have to create a new object for each item. That adds up for large lists

Comment: Thanks, I heard that this is quiet an expensive operation ? Maybe its better to just use Stream<Integer> instead of IntStream ?, Although I am sure it won't matter for smaller numbers

Comment: That still matters as by passing an int to an ArrayList etc or Stream, Java boxes it for you into an Integer.

Comment: You are already using `boxed()` so there’s no point in worrying how expensive that is. You just have to move the already existing `boxed()` before the `sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())` step.